# Some questions with the source of the libuv?

Tags: c++, libuv

Recently,I read the source of libuv.
There are some questions when read the QUEUE.h

**Firstly:**
The macro define below：

```
typedef void *QUEUE[2];
#define QUEUE_NEXT(q)       (*(QUEUE **) &((*(q))[0]))
#define QUEUE_PREV(q)       (*(QUEUE **) &((*(q))[1]))
```

Can I redefine the QUEUE_PREV(q) as:

```
#define QUEUE_PREVR(q)       ((QUEUE *) &((*(q))[1]))
```

**what is the diffrence between them?**

**Secondly:**
I try the code below:

```
typedef struct{
     int i1;
     int i5 ;
     int i6;
}s1;

typedef struct 
{
    int j1;
    int j2;
    int j3;
}s2;

s1 i = { 1, 2 ,61};
s2 j = { 97, 99, 90 };
QUEUE a;
a[0] = &i;
a[1] = &j;
cout << (QUEUE*)(&((*(&a))[1])) << endl;
cout << *(QUEUE*)(&((*(&a))[1])) << endl;
```

**The result is same on the console,But why? Don't the "*"  works??
I write this code with VS2013.**

Answer (score 3):

#### Firstly, what is the diffrence between them?

You are right in saying the type is the same, but is the value? Let's look at what we got:

> [QUEUE is typedef'd as an array 2 of pointer to void](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void%20*QUEUE%5B2%5D%3B)

Ok, what about: `&((*(q))[1]))`

- taking `q` which is a `QUEUE*`.
- dereference `q` yielding a `QUEUE`.
- then indexing its second element which is a `void *` pointing to the previous `QUEUE`
- then take the address of that pointer (yielding a `void**`).

Let's call the result `&r` where `r` is of type `void*`.

---

`#define QUEUE_PREV(q)       (*(QUEUE **) &r)`

`&r` which is a `void**` is cast to `QUEUE **`. Then it is dereferenced as the `QUEUE*` it is, i.e.: **Result has value `r` and type `QUEUE*`**.

---

So far, so good. How does that differ from your attempt?

`#define QUEUE_PREVR(q)       ((QUEUE *) &r)`

We cast the `&r` (a `void **`) to a `QUEUE*`. While this is legal, we lost an indirection that was present. **Result has value `&r` and type `QUEUE*`**. The type is the same, the value isn't.

---

#### Secondly: Why doesn't the "*" work?

```
cout << (QUEUE*)&aa << endl;
cout << *(QUEUE*)&aa << endl;
```

In the first line, you `cout` the `&r` pointer. The value of the pointer is thus printed. In the second line, you `cout` a `QUEUE` which is an array. using an array outside of `sizeof` always converts the result to a pointer to its first element (`&r[0]`). And we know that `&r == &r[0]`.

#### Finally,

`QUEUE` isn't meant to be used that way, check out [`src/threadpool.c`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/c272f1f1bc0bda625e6441d798c110b4064a6ce2/src/threadpool.c) instead for a use case.